# spacy 3 NER Scorer() throws TypeError: score() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, spacy-3

Running into the following error when trying to get scores on my test set using `Scorer`

> TypeError: score() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

```
import spacy 
from spacy.tokens import Span
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.training import *
from spacy.scorer import Scorer
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding

def evaluate(ner_model, testing_data):
    scorer = Scorer()

    for input_, annot in testing_data:
        doc_gold_text = ner_model.make_doc(input_)
        example = Example.from_dict(doc_gold_text, {"entities": annot})
        pred_value = ner_model(input_)
        
    return scorer.score(pred_value, example)

print(evaluate(nlp_updated, testing_tagged))
```

Where testing_tagged:

```
testing_tagged = [
    ("Who was Hamlet?", [(8,14,'PERSON')]),
    ("Have you ever met Rome?", [(18,22,'LOC')])
]
```

Expected output is where `p`, `r` and `f` are not 0:

```
{'uas': 0.0, 'las': 0.0, 'las_per_type': {'': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}}, 'ents_p': 0.0, 'ents_r': 0.0, 'ents_f': 0.0, 'ents_per_type': {'PERSON': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}, 'LOC': {'p': 0.0, 'r': 0.0, 'f': 0.0}}, 'tags_acc': 0.0, 'token_acc': 100.0, 'textcat_score': 0.0, 'textcats_per_cat': {}}
```

I initially had this working with the `GoldParse` function instead of `Example.from_dict` - but I upgraded to Spacy 3.0.5 and I can't understand why this error is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since spaCy v3, `scorer.score` just takes a list of examples. Each `Example`object holds two `Doc` objects:

- one `reference` doc with the gold-standard annotations, created for
  example from the given `annot` dictionary
- one `predicted` doc with the predictions. The scorer will then compare the two.

So you want something like this:

```py
from spacy.training import Example
examples = []
for ...:
    example = Example.from_dict(text, {"entities": annot})
    example.predicted = ner_model(example.predicted)
    examples.append(example)
scorer.score(examples)
```