# How to print PRF values for a NER model using spaCy v3?

Tags: performance, spacy-3

## Context

I am currently working on a NER model for the Romanian Legal Domain. I began creating a custom model using spaCy v2 (v2.2.4), for which I successfully implemented a code to find the PRF values. Now, after I made the transition to spaCy v3 (v3.0.6), I find it difficult to evaluate the performance of my model.

## Problem

I tried to do the following:

- Use the same code in spaCy v3.0.6. like that for spaCy v2.2.4 (problem: GoldParser is not present in spaCy v3.0.6)
- Use spaCy v2.2.4 to train the v3.0.6 model (problem: I think that the models are not saved in the same way regardless of their version)
- Use get_ner_prf() (problem: I did not understand how to create the parameter of type Example and I am also not sure how to call the function)

## Resources

Here is a list of all the resources I have at the moment:

- Config files for the v3.0.6 model (and all the other necessary files)
- Train and test data in the old spaCy format
- Saved v3.0.6 custom model for Romanian

## Request

I would be grateful to receive a code that works for spaCy v3.0.6 and calculates the PRF values - preferably individual results for every entity type. Also, it will be great if the code only makes use of the resources aforementioned. If any other information is needed, I am glad to send it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no longer looking for an answer because I figured it out.

The discussions at the following links:

https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/8178

[spacy 3 NER Scorer() throws TypeError: score() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67229277/spacy-3-ner-scorer-throws-typeerror-score-takes-2-positional-arguments-but)

were very useful and I was able to write the following code (in case anyone that reads the current discussion may still find it difficult to make the transition):

```py
# TRAIN_DATA format
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ("Who was Hamlet?", [(8,14,'PER')]),
    ("Have you ever met Rome?", [(18,22,'LOC')])
]

import spacy 
from spacy.tokens import Span
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.training import *
from spacy.scorer import Scorer
from spacy.util import minibatch, compounding

nlp = spacy.load("./output/model-best")

# evaluate function
def evaluate(ner_model, testing_data):
    scorer = Scorer()
    examples = []
    for input_, annot in testing_data:
        doc_gold_text = ner_model.make_doc(input_)
        example = Example.from_dict(doc_gold_text, {"entities": annot})
        example.predicted = ner_model(input_)
        examples.append(example)
        
    return scorer.score(examples)

# print the results
print(evaluate(nlp, TRAIN_DATA))
```

The output is in the following format:

```py
{'token_acc': 1.0, 'token_p': 1.0, 'token_r': 1.0, 'token_f': 1.0, 'sents_p': 1.0, 'sents_r': 1.0, 'sents_f': 1.0, 'tag_acc': None, 'pos_acc': None, 'morph_acc': None, 'morph_per_feat': None, 'dep_uas': None, 'dep_las': None, 'dep_las_per_type': None, 'ents_p': 0.9833333333333333, 'ents_r': 0.9365079365079365, 'ents_f': 0.9593495934959351, 'ents_per_type': {'LAW': {'p': 1.0, 'r': 1.0, 'f': 1.0}, 'LOC': {'p': 1.0, 'r': 0.6666666666666666, 'f': 0.8}, 'ORG': {'p': 0.9565217391304348, 'r': 0.9565217391304348, 'f': 0.9565217391304348}, 'TIME': {'p': 1.0, 'r': 1.0, 'f': 1.0}, 'PER': {'p': 1.0, 'r': 1.0, 'f': 1.0}}, 'cats_score': 0.0, 'cats_score_desc': 'macro F', 'cats_micro_p': 0.0, 'cats_micro_r': 0.0, 'cats_micro_f': 0.0, 'cats_macro_p': 0.0, 'cats_macro_r': 0.0, 'cats_macro_f': 0.0, 'cats_macro_auc': 0.0, 'cats_f_per_type': {}, 'cats_auc_per_type': {}}
```

If anything seems wrong, please don't hesitate to mention.