# How to generate Precision, Recall and F-score in Named Entity Recognition using Spacy v3? Seeking ents_p, ents_r, ents_f for a small custom NER model

Tags: python, named-entity-recognition, precision-recall, spacy-3

The example code is given below, you may add one or more entities in this example for training purposes (You may also use a blank model with small examples for demonstration). I am seeking a complete working solution for custom NER model evaluation (precision, recall, f-score), Thanks in advance to all NLP experts.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
example_text = "Agra is famous for Tajmahal, The CEO of Facebook will visit India shortly to meet Murari Mahaseth and to visit Tajmahal"
ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")
doc = nlp(example_text)
for e in doc.ents:
    print(e.text + ' - ' + str(e.start_char) + ' - ' + str(e.end_char) + ' - ' + e.label_ + ' - ' + str(
        spacy.explain(e.label_)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a brief example :

```
import spacy
from spacy.scorer import Scorer
from spacy.tokens import Doc
from spacy.training.example import Example

examples = [
    ('Who is Talha Tayyab?',
     {(7, 19, 'PERSON')}),
    ('I like London and Berlin.',
     {(7, 13, 'LOC'), (18, 24, 'LOC')}),
     ('Agra is famous for Tajmahal, The CEO of Facebook will visit India shortly to meet Murari Mahaseth and to visit Tajmahal.',
     {(0, 4, 'LOC'), (40, 48, 'ORG'), (60, 65, 'GPE'), (82, 97, 'PERSON'), (111, 119, 'GPE')})
]

def my_evaluate(ner_model, examples):
    scorer = Scorer()
    example = []
    for input_, annotations in examples:
        pred = ner_model(input_)
        print(pred,annotations)
        temp = Example.from_dict(pred, dict.fromkeys(annotations))
        example.append(temp)
    scores = scorer.score(example)
    return scores

ner_model = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') # for spaCy's pretrained use 'en_core_web_sm'
results = my_evaluate(ner_model, examples)
print(results)
```

As, I said this is just an example you can make changes according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution @Talha Tayyab. I will also appreciate your guidance with the same example provided by you for the spacy version 2.3.5.

Comment: Can you clarify why you need to use spaCy v2? v3 has been out for over a year now.

Comment: @MurariMahaseth above mention program is for spacy 3.

Comment: Yes I tested the above program in spacy v3. It is running well and helped me.
Sir @polm23 , Although it is not necessary to use spacy v2, but during learning and exploring NER via video lectures on youtube, sometimes I am bound to use Spacy v2 because many lectures explanation and libraries dependencies are given in spacy v2.

Comment: @MurariMahaseth can you please accept my answer by clicking the 'tick' mark? For `spacy v2` : `GoldParse` from `spacy.gold` is used. But, `spacy v3` has made it much simpler.

Comment: Why are the ents results coming back with "None"?

'ents_p': None, 'ents_r': None, 'ents_f': None, 'ents_per_type': None,

Comment: You may also try this solution for ents_p, ents_r and ents_f [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67689509/7084804)